# php smarty is there a way to log who logs in to the site?

Tags: php, html, smarty, logfiles

I guess if it is possible, that it will be some crazy convoluted way, but my client has asked me to try to create a log file of people who log in to the site.

Is there a way to do this? I don't know php/smarty so well, I'm more of a layout person.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

oh.. PHP Smarty is a PHP templating engine. It doesn't have anything to do with visitor tracking.

If you want to track visits to your website the best choice is **Google Analytics**. http://www.google.com/analytics/

Comment: We have analytics installed, I guess he was thinking "Which users login when." Thanks.

Comment: Of course this can be done from PHP but using analytics you could also see access to the restricted, awailable to one user  subpage. If you know user 'tom' can access page: www.blah.com/tom you will see traffic for this page only for this particular user thus you will be able to track his log-ins.

Answer (score 3):

Smarty is just a template engine. To find out who is logging in, you'd need to look at the CMS/framework/whatever is processing that login.

Do you know what is powering the site? e.g. WordPress, Drupal, .. etc?

Comment: Thanks. I'll see what I can do.

Comment: I have no idea, it's an order processing system called Livecart www.livecart.com.

Comment: @Kyle - yikes. Unless that software provides the reporting already.. someone's going to have to make some core edits to log that information..

Answer (score 1):

What system do you have managing users and logins? That'll be what you use to log who's accessing your site. Smarty just takes care of the templating, nothing else.